# use :focus-within to only apply focus if the focus is a button

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to apply a style on an element only if the focus is on the `input` and not the `button`?

Here is a simple HTML example:

```html
<div>
  <input />
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Here is the SCSS to go alongside, as this doesn't seem to work...

```scss
.div:focus-within:is(button) {
  // Apply style to the div only if the input is focused.
  // As the button has its own focus style.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:has()` selector:

```css
div:focus-within:has( *:not(button):focus ) {

    background-color: green;
}

div:focus-within:has( button:focus ) {

    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <button>Button</button>

  <input type="text" />

</div>

<div>

  <button>Button</button>

  <input type="text" />

</div>

<div>

  <button>Button</button>

  <input type="text" />

</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know you could use pseudo selectors with in the :has pseudo selector. Thats cool!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you can get rid of the focus-within part, it's redundant with the :has( :focus)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That doesn't seem to work. I get the outline on the div and the selected button.